# protected not visible outside the module

Tags: fortran

The following code snippet

```
module test
  private
  protected :: a
  integer :: a = 0
end module test
  use test
  implicit none
  print*, a
end program
```

results in an error, with both gfortran and ifort, that the variable 'a' must have an explicit type. I also get an error if 'protected' is moved into the line where 'a' is declared. I don't get an error if 'a' has the public attribute (remove the 'private' keyword, put 'public :: a' after 'private', or I put 'public' into the same line as 'a = 0'). I get the desired read-only public behavior only with

```
  public :: a
  integer, protected :: a = 0
```

So, unless 'protected' is accompanied by 'public' it acts like 'private'. Am I doing something wrong? I am trying to follow "Modern Fortran" by Clerman and Spector where they suggest the module header to always have the form

```
private
protected :: <access-id-list>
public :: <access-id-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible accessibility attributes for an object are `public` and `private`.  `protected` is not an accessibilty attribute, although the grouping of the three may well suggest that.

In particular, specifying the `protected` attribute doesn't imply the `public` attribute so the default accessibility of `private` applies to the variable `a`.

Comment: So by using the protected statement, it is assumed that the names following it are declared public elsewhere. Otherwise the variables would be private and protected, which wouldn't make sense. Then I can agree with the authors that this is indeed good coding style. This puzzled me for some time.

Comment: Yes.  Being protected limits a variable which is use associated (the "outside the module"), but the private attribute prevents it from being use associated.  There may be something exotic when being a private target, but I'm not sure as the entity itself is still not being use associated, rather a pointer would be.

Comment: private, protected, target is probably legal, but changing it through the pointer outside of the module shouldn't be.